# iOS 8: TableView Scroll to RowIndex is not working

Tags: uitableview, ios8, header, searchbar

using this line of code in viewDidLoad after my table get reloaded.

`[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];`

Unfortunately, it's not working for me. 
throwing Exception:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).`

i want to hide header section of tableView on application start.

header section contain searchBar. so i want it to be hidden when app start.
i searched really hard but couldn't find the exact answer to my problem. so as last resort, i had to type it myself.

Regards,

A Naive iOS Developer.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when a section has no rows. In this case use NSNotFound. You can find this in UITableView Class Reference.

**Obj-C**

```
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

**Swift**

```
let scrollIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: NSNotFound, inSection: 0)
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(scrollIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
```